# MySQL simple select statement, create auto increment if row value different then previous one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query so far:

```
SET @cnt = 0;
SELECT (
  @cnt := @cnt +1
) AS rowNumber, brand
FROM  `cars`
```

which returns the following:

```
rowNumber | brand
1         | fiat
2         | fiat
3         | fiat
4         | bmw
5         | bmw
6         | mercedes
7         | mercedes
8         | tesla
9         | tesla
```

However I want to achieve this output:

```
rowNumber | brand
1         | fiat
1         | fiat
1         | fiat
2         | bmw
2         | bmw
3         | mercedes
3         | mercedes
4         | tesla
4         | tesla
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using another variables:

```
select (@rn := if(@b = brand, @rn,
                  if(@b := brand, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                 )
       ) as rowNumber, brand
from `cars` c cross join
     (select @b := '', @rn := 0) params
order by brand;
```

Comment: that works exactly as I wished for! Thank you very much!